# Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know if this is a problem for this site.

I am looking for all possible analytic functions $f:\Bbb{C}\longrightarrow\Bbb{C}$ such that for any $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, $|f(x+yi)| \leq (1+|y|)e^x$. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Find out something about $g(z) = f(z)e^{-z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You mean $f(z)e^{z}$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No, I meant what I wrote.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see. I was looking at it the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conveniently, we have

$$e^x = \lvert e^{x+iy}\rvert$$

for all $x,\, y \in \mathbb{R}$, so multiplying $f$ with $e^{-(x+iy)} = \frac{1}{e^{x+iy}}$ gives us an analytic function $g \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with the estimate

$$\lvert g(x+iy)\rvert = \lvert f(x+iy)\rvert\cdot\lvert e^{-(x+iy)}\rvert \leqslant (1 + \lvert y\rvert)e^x\cdot e^{-x} = 1 + \lvert y\rvert.$$

In particular, $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1 + \lvert z\rvert$. The Cauchy estimates now tell us that $g$ belongs to a rather small class of functions, and using the smaller bound $1 + \lvert y\rvert$ reduces the possibilities even further.